# IF condition with Azuredevops variableGroupp values not working

Tags: azure-devops

I was trying to below logic to my helm release task in azuredevops task, where I want to decide the image tag version and replica count on the basis of input variable value from the variable group. But the logic is not working as expected.

```
1) prod weigtage (100), canaryweightage (0) , canaryconfirmed(false)          --- > common-helm-chart.deployment.image.tag=$(currentVersion)
                                                                                canarydeploymentreplica(0)
        ${{ if and(eq(variables['canaryweightage'], 0 ), eq(variables['prodweightage'], 100 ), eq(variables['canaryconfirmed'], 'false'))}}:
           common-helm-chart.deployment.agentpool=$(targetNodePool),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.agentpool=$(targetNodePool),common-helm-chart.deployment.image.tag=$(currentVersion),common-helm-chart.deployment.weight=$(prodweightage),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.image.tag=$(releaseVersionTagDocker),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.replicaCount=0,common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.weight=$(canaryweightage)

##########################################################  
2) Not[[prod weigtage (100), canaryweightage (0) , canaryconfirmed(true)]]   ---> common-helm-chart.deployment.image.tag=$(currentVersion)                                                                 
                                                                               canarydeploymentreplica(2)
        ${{ if and(ne(variables['canaryweightage'], 0 ), ne(variables['prodweightage'], 100 ), ne(variables['canaryconfirmed'], 'true'))}}:                                                                            
               
        common-helm-chart.deployment.agentpool=$(targetNodePool),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.agentpool=$(targetNodePool),common-helm-chart.deployment.image.tag=$(currentVersion),common-helm-chart.deployment.weight=$(prodweightage),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.image.tag=$(releaseVersionTagDocker),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.replicaCount=2,common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.weight=$(canaryweightage)

###############################################################################################################
                                                                               
3)prod weigtage (0), canaryweightage (100) , canaryconfirmed(false)         ----> common-helm-chart.deployment.image.tag=$(currentVersion)
                                                                                canarydeploymentreplica(2)  
        ${{ if and(eq(variables['canaryweightage'], 100 ), eq(variables['prodweightage'], 0 ), eq(variables['canaryconfirmed'], 'false'))}}:
 
        common-helm-chart.deployment.agentpool=$(targetNodePool),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.agentpool=$(targetNodePool),common-helm-chart.deployment.image.tag=$(currentVersion),common-helm-chart.deployment.weight=$(prodweightage),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.image.tag=$(releaseVersionTagDocker),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.replicaCount=2,common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.weight=$(canaryweightage)

####################################################################################################################                                                                                
4) prod weigtage (0), canaryweightage (100) , canaryconfirmed(true)         ----> common-helm-chart.deployment.image.tag=${releaseVersionTagDocker}$
                                                                                canarydeploymentreplica(2)
        ${{ if and(eq(variables['canaryweightage'], 0 ), eq(variables['prodweightage'], 100 ), eq(variables['canaryconfirmed'], 'true'))}}:
        common-helm-chart.deployment.agentpool=$(targetNodePool),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.agentpool=$(targetNodePool),common-helm-chart.deployment.image.tag=$(releaseVersionTagDocker),common-helm-chart.deployment.weight=$(prodweightage),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.image.tag=$(releaseVersionTagDocker),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.replicaCount=2,common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.weight=$(canaryweightage)
                                                                                
##############################################################################################################################                                                                              
5) prod weigtage (100), canaryweightage (0) , canaryconfirmed(true)         ----> common-helm-chart.deployment.image.tag=${releaseVersionTagDocker}$
                                                                                canarydeploymentreplica(0)  
        ${{ if and(eq(variables['canaryweightage'], 0 ), eq(variables['prodweightage'], 100 ), eq(variables['canaryconfirmed'], 'true'))}}:
        common-helm-chart.deployment.agentpool=$(targetNodePool),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.agentpool=$(targetNodePool),common-helm-chart.deployment.image.tag=$(releaseVersionTagDocker),common-helm-chart.deployment.weight=$(prodweightage),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.image.tag=$(releaseVersionTagDocker),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.replicaCount=0,common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.weight=$(canaryweightage)
```

For this to work under azurepipeline Jobs variables, I first converted the VG values to variables.

```
variables:
    - name: canaryweightage
      value: $(canaryweight)
    - name: prodweightage
      value: $(weight) 
    - name: canaryconfirmed
      value: $(canaryverified)
```

Then under the task added the conditions and above logic as above.

```
- task: HelmDeploy@0
  displayName: 'Deploy service - Dry run'
  inputs:
    azureSubscriptionEndpoint: ${{ parameters.subscriptionEndpoint }}
    azureResourceGroup: $(aksRg)
    kubernetesCluster: $(aksName)
    ${{ if parameters.helmNamespace }}:
      namespace: ${{ parameters.helmNamespace }}
    ${{ if not(parameters.helmNamespace) }}:
      namespace: ${{ parameters.namespace }}
    command: upgrade
    chartType: FilePath
    chartPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/${{ parameters.environment }}-helm
    releaseName: ${{ parameters.appName }}
    arguments: '--dry-run --timeout ${{ parameters.helmTimeout }} -f $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/${{ parameters.environment }}-helm/environments/${{ parameters.environment }}.yaml'
    failOnStderr: false
    ${{ if and(eq(variables['canaryweightage'], 0 ), eq(variables['prodweightage'], 100 ), eq(variables['canaryconfirmed'], 'false'))}}:
      overrideValues: common-helm-chart.deployment.agentpool=$(targetNodePool),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.agentpool=$(targetNodePool),common-helm-chart.deployment.image.tag=$(currentVersion),common-helm-chart.deployment.weight=$(prodweightage),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.image.tag=$(releaseVersionTagDocker),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.replicaCount=0,common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.weight=$(canaryweightage)
    ${{ if and(ne(variables['canaryweightage'], 0 ), ne(variables['prodweightage'], 100 ), ne(variables['canaryconfirmed'], 'true'))}}:
      overrideValues: common-helm-chart.deployment.agentpool=$(targetNodePool),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.agentpool=$(targetNodePool),common-helm-chart.deployment.image.tag=$(currentVersion),common-helm-chart.deployment.weight=$(prodweightage),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.image.tag=$(releaseVersionTagDocker),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.replicaCount=2,common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.weight=$(canaryweightage)
    ${{ if and(eq(variables['canaryweightage'], 100 ), eq(variables['prodweightage'], 0 ), eq(variables['canaryconfirmed'], 'false'))}}:
      overrideValues: common-helm-chart.deployment.agentpool=$(targetNodePool),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.agentpool=$(targetNodePool),common-helm-chart.deployment.image.tag=$(currentVersion),common-helm-chart.deployment.weight=$(prodweightage),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.image.tag=$(releaseVersionTagDocker),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.replicaCount=2,common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.weight=$(canaryweightage)
    ${{ if and(eq(variables['canaryweightage'], 100 ), eq(variables['prodweightage'], 0 ), eq(variables['canaryconfirmed'], 'true'))}}:
      overrideValues: common-helm-chart.deployment.agentpool=$(targetNodePool),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.agentpool=$(targetNodePool),common-helm-chart.deployment.image.tag=$(releaseVersionTagDocker),common-helm-chart.deployment.weight=$(prodweightage),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.image.tag=$(releaseVersionTagDocker),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.replicaCount=2,common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.weight=$(canaryweightage)
    ${{ if and(eq(variables['canaryweightage'], 0 ), eq(variables['prodweightage'], 100 ), eq(variables['canaryconfirmed'], 'true'))}}:
      overrideValues: common-helm-chart.deployment.agentpool=$(targetNodePool),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.agentpool=$(targetNodePool),common-helm-chart.deployment.image.tag=$(releaseVersionTagDocker),common-helm-chart.deployment.weight=$(prodweightage),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.image.tag=$(releaseVersionTagDocker),common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.replicaCount=0,common-helm-chart.canarydeployment.weight=$(canaryweightage)
```

When we tested the  the scenario 1[prod weigtage (100), canaryweightage (0) , canaryconfirmed(false)  ] its not working as expected and ,instead of keeping the canary replica to 0, it was giving 2 replicas.

Comment: I don't see in your question a description of the error you get.

Comment: Usually, it works as expected. Try to add a step just to print the values of your variables. This will help to debug your yaml.

Comment: What language is the `${{ ... }}` expression syntax?  It's neither Bourne shell syntax nor Helm/Go-template syntax.

Comment: It's yaml pipeline syntax for parameters and variables explore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

Based on the discussions, here is an update.

You have succeeded using conditional insertion (`${if}` is a template expression expanding at compile time) to dynamically set `namespace`; however, you cannot set `overrideValues` with the evaluation of the variables `canaryweightage` `prodweightage` and `canaryconfirmed`. This is because their values are retrieved from the corresponding variables `canaryweight` `weight` and `canaryverified` **in your variable group**, whose values **cannot** be referenced at compile time.

For this, I have suggested using parameters instead of using variables in a variable group to define `canaryweightage` `prodweightage` and `canaryconfirmed` (see the workaround in next part), because parameter values are accessible at compile time. This is also why the template syntax is working to dynamically set `namespace`.

As another option, you may also reference a set of variables from a [variable template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops&pivots=templates-includes#variable-reuse)/parameter template instead of referencing variables in a variable group. You can defined variables/parameters in a **separate** YAML file in your repo (the YAML file can be located from the same repository of your pipipeline or from another repo as a repository resource) and the variables in it can also be expanded at compile time.

```
# VariableTemplate.yml
variables:
  canaryweight: 0
  weight: 100
  canaryverified: true
```

```
# Main pipeline YAML


variables:
# - group: VG-IF
- template: VariableTemplate.yml

jobs:
- job:
  variables: 
    - name: canaryweightage
      value: ${{ variables.canaryweight }}
    - name: prodweightage
      value: ${{ variables.weight }}
    - name: canaryconfirmed
      value: ${{ variables.canaryverified }}
  steps:
  - script: |
      echo "====================Expand canaryweightage===================="
      echo "Expand canaryweightage in template syntax: ${{ variables.canaryweightage }}"
      echo "Expand canaryweightage in marco syntax: $(canaryweightage)"
      echo "====================Expand canaryweight in VG===================="
      echo "Expand canaryweight in template syntax: ${{ variables.canaryweight }}"
      echo "Expand canaryweight in marco syntax: $(canaryweight)"
      echo "====================Expand prodweightage===================="
      echo "Expand prodweightage in template syntax: ${{ variables.prodweightage }}"
      echo "Expand prodweightage in marco syntax: $(prodweightage)"
      echo "====================Expand weight in VG===================="
      echo "Expand weight in template syntax: ${{ variables.weight }}"
      echo "Expand weight in marco syntax: $(weight)"
    displayName: Test varaible syntax
  - ${{ if eq(variables['canaryconfirmed'], 'true') }}: 
    - script: |
          echo "====================Expand canaryconfirmed===================="
          echo "Expand canaryconfirmed in template syntax: ${{ variables.canaryconfirmed }}"
          echo "Expand canaryconfirmed in marco syntax: $(canaryconfirmed)"
          echo "====================Expand canaryverified in VG===================="
          echo "Expand canaryverified in template syntax: ${{ variables.canaryverified }}"
          echo "Expand canaryverified in marco syntax: $(canaryverified)"
      displayName: Step under evaluation of conditional insertion
```

The `Step under evaluation of conditional insertion` is populated as expected.

[image]

### Legacy

According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

> To reference a variable group, use macro syntax (`$(MyVariable)`)or a runtime expression (`$[variables.MyVariable]`).

Both macro syntax and runtime syntax are processed during runtime **after** compile time.

However, I am afraid we cannot expand the variable from a variable group  within template syntax (`${ expression }`) at **compile time**. In your case, you would evaluate the variables defined by corresponding variables from a variable group in conditional insertion (`${if}`), the value is not expanded as expected and will return `Null`.

The behavior can be reproduced with below sample. At **compile time**, there are no values for the variables `canaryweight` `weight` and `canaryverified` in the variable group, therefore the evaluation of the variables `canaryweightage` `prodweightage` and `canaryconfirmed` in conditional insertion will return `Null`. It is until **runtime**, they can retrieve values from the variable group.

[image]

```
variables:
- group: VG-IF
jobs:
- job:
  variables: 
    - name: canaryweightage
      value: $(canaryweight)
    - name: prodweightage
      value: $[variables.weight]
    - name: canaryconfirmed
      value: $(canaryverified)
  steps:
  - script: |
      echo "====================Expand canaryweightage===================="
      echo "Expand canaryweightage in template syntax: ${{ variables.canaryweightage }}"
      echo "Expand canaryweightage in marco syntax: $(canaryweightage)"
      echo "====================Expand canaryweight in VG===================="
      echo "Expand canaryweight in template syntax: ${{ variables.canaryweight }}"
      echo "Expand canaryweight in marco syntax: $(canaryweight)"
      echo "====================Expand prodweightage===================="
      echo "Expand prodweightage in template syntax: ${{ variables.prodweightage }}"
      echo "Expand prodweightage in marco syntax: $(prodweightage)"
      echo "====================Expand weight in VG===================="
      echo "Expand weight in template syntax: ${{ variables.weight }}"
      echo "Expand weight in marco syntax: $(weight)"
  - ${{ if eq(variables['canaryconfirmed'], 'true') }}: 
    - script: |
          echo "====================Expand canaryconfirmed===================="
          echo "Expand canaryconfirmed in template syntax: ${{ variables.canaryconfirmed }}"
          echo "Expand canaryconfirmed in marco syntax: $(canaryconfirmed)"
          echo "====================Expand canaryverified in VG===================="
          echo "Expand canaryverified in template syntax: ${{ variables.canaryverified }}"
          echo "Expand canaryverified in marco syntax: $(canaryverified)"
```

[image]

For this, you may consider using parameters instead, whose values are accessible at compile time and we can set their values at queue time.

```
# variables:
# - group: VG-IF
parameters:
- name: canaryweight
  default: 0
  values:
  - 0
  - 100
- name: weight
  default: 100
  values:
  - 0
  - 100
- name: canaryverified
  default: true
  values:
  - true
  - false
jobs:
- job:
  variables: 
    - name: canaryweightage
      value: ${{ parameters.canaryweight }}
    - name: prodweightage
      value: ${{ parameters.weight }}
    - name: canaryconfirmed
      value: ${{ parameters.canaryverified }}
  steps:
  - script: |
      echo "====================Expand canaryweightage===================="
      echo "Expand canaryweightage in template syntax: ${{ variables.canaryweightage }}"
      echo "Expand canaryweightage in marco syntax: $(canaryweightage)"
      echo "====================Expand canaryweight in VG===================="
      echo "Expand canaryweight in template syntax: ${{ variables.canaryweight }}"
      echo "Expand canaryweight in marco syntax: $(canaryweight)"
      echo "====================Expand prodweightage===================="
      echo "Expand prodweightage in template syntax: ${{ variables.prodweightage }}"
      echo "Expand prodweightage in marco syntax: $(prodweightage)"
      echo "====================Expand weight in VG===================="
      echo "Expand weight in template syntax: ${{ variables.weight }}"
      echo "Expand weight in marco syntax: $(weight)"
  - ${{ if eq(variables['canaryconfirmed'], 'true') }}: 
    - script: |
          echo "====================Expand canaryconfirmed===================="
          echo "Expand canaryconfirmed in template syntax: ${{ variables.canaryconfirmed }}"
          echo "Expand canaryconfirmed in marco syntax: $(canaryconfirmed)"
          echo "====================Expand canaryverified in VG===================="
          echo "Expand canaryverified in template syntax: ${{ variables.canaryverified }}"
          echo "Expand canaryverified in marco syntax: $(canaryverified)"
```

[image]

See more details in the documents below.

[Expressions - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops)

[Understand variable syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax)

Hope the information helps.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, i will chek and let u know. But in your testing the 1st and 3rd were same, but gt different output. Not sure why that behavior.

Comment: - script: |
      echo "====================Expand canaryweightage===================="
      echo "Expand canaryweightage in template syntax: ${{ variables.canaryweightage }}"
      echo "Expand canaryweightage in marco syntax: $(canaryweightage)"
      echo "====================Expand prodweightage===================="
      echo "Expand prodweightage in template syntax: ${{ variables.prodweightage }}"
      echo "Expand prodweightage in marco syntax: $(prodweightage)"

Comment: I tested your suggestion, which will not meet my requirement. here my requirement is to pick the value from variable group itself so that i can re-run the stage alone to get these values picked and corresponding conditions applied. but not the entire pipeline.

Comment: is there any way to achieve this over bash script or azurecli  devops task ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that `in your testing the 1st and 3rd were same`. 1st test variable is `canaryweightage`; 3rd test variable is `prodweightage`. They are copied based on your original post, right?

Comment: As mentioned, we **cannot** reference variables in a variable group at compile time. This is by design. You need to using condition insertion(`${if}`) to dynamically set ` overrideValues`; that template syntax `${}` is expanded at compile time. That's why you the insertion is not expanded as expected. For this, I suggest using parameters, which is similar to your `namespace` `${if}` condition. `bash` script and `azurecli` task execute at runtime **after** compile time, may I know what you would like to use them for?

Comment: You have already succeeded in using parameter values to dynamically set `namespace`, you can set `overrideValues` the same way with parameter values(see my workaround in the answer). But you should **not** reference variables in a **variable group** within **template syntax at compile time**. Instead of defining variables in a variable group, you may opt to use variable template]; you can defined variables in a separate YAML file and the variables in it could be expanded at compile time. I will update the answer on this.